# How to generate a SSH key using Git Gui?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, git-gui

I am trying to generate a SSH Public Key for https://pantheon.io/docs/ssh-keys/.  The process I followed is: Open up 
Git Gui> Help> Show SSH Key> Generate Key.  That is when I get the following error.

child process exited abnormally
/usr/bin/sh: /usr/bin/ssh-keygen: Permission denied

I need to create an SSH key to use on pantheon.io

I have WinSCP and PuTTY installed and I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise.

Any help is appreciated, Thank You.